# Infinite loop when trying to sort array in v-for

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to sort an array in a v-for (I also tried to inline it).
The issue is that the sorting method is being called too many times, appearing to be infinite.

```
<div v-for="asset in sortBinaries(props.row.assets)" :key="asset.url">
</div>
```

```
sortBinaries(binaries) {
  return binaries.sort((a, b) => this.fieldSorter(a, b, ['arch', 'type']));
},

fieldSorter(a, b, fields) {
    var dir = [], i, l = fields.length;
    
    fields = fields.map(function(o, i) {
      if (o[0] === "-") {
        dir[i] = -1;
        o = o.substring(1);
      } else {
        dir[i] = 1;
      }

      return o;
    });

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        var o = fields[i];

        if (a[o] > b[o]) 
          return dir[i];
        if (a[o] < b[o]) 
          return -(dir[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The v-for is located in a detail slot of a Buefy table. So I need the reference to the `props.row` object.

Is there any way to sort the array when displaying, instead of treating all data first?

The array that I'm sorting is small (6 entries max), but the whole set can get bigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use computed instead of sort inline

For infinite loop, if you use sort inline, everytime this template render, the sort function inline will be invoked.

Use computed to sort your data is a good idea. Your templated will rerender just after computed changed.

```
<div v-for="asset in sortedBinaries" :key="asset.url">
```

```
computed: {
  sortedBinaries() {
    return this.row.assets.sort((a, b) => this.fieldSorter(a, b, ['arch', 'type']));
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably the right answer, but can you expand on this? Maybe explain why using computed instead of inline is a good approach and possibly include a code sample.

Comment: Oh, so `this` refers to the accessor inside the Buefy table?

Comment: `computed ` has lazy compute strategy design by Vue, only if the computed items subcriber change, computed item change.

Comment: Every components instance (like Buefy table), has their own `this`, refers components instance. God, my english ...